# google sheets : Formula works differently than usual

Tags: google-sheets

Hi today i got a document shared by my friends. I've just found out that this document/spreadsheet doesn't work as normally. Some formula just doesn't work here.

for example , normally if i use :

```
={1,2,3}
```

it should normally create a row with 3 columns (3 cells each contains 1,2,3 respectively).

But in this document , i got : "formula parse error"

Also found out that when i try to use some formulas , for example the filter(), the help/documentation shows something really different.Pls check my screenshot, normally it uses comma (,) separator while this document using semicolon (;). I'm confused what is wrong ? I'm suspecting that this maybe about google sheet versioning. Am i correct ? or something else ?

If yes, how can i convert this old version document into the latest one ?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your sheet is not US-based, therefore you need to use:

```
={1\2\3}
```

---

```
                      ENGLISH SHEETS         NON-ENGLISH SHEETS

ROW ARRAY                    ,                        \

COLUMN ARRAY                 ;                        ;

FX ARGUMENT SEPARATOR        ,                        ;
```

language of the spreadsheet can be found in the settings:

[image]